# How to implement Kerberos in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, kerberos

I am doing a R&D for implement kerberos client in Node.JS. I am using this node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos

My Node implementation is:

```
var kerberos = require('kerberos');
const kerberosClient = new kerberos.KerberosClient();
```

When I run `node .\kerberos.js` output of the console as below:

```
ReferenceError: kerberos is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node.js\kafka-node\kerberos.js:3:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I wasn't able to find an example or any tutorial for implementing Kerberos. If anyone can suggest a tutorial or example, that will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Read the unit tests: https://github.com/mongodb-js/kerberos/tree/master/test Kerberos is a pretty "low level" thing, so tutorials are not something on the typical maintainers agenda. They basically expect if you want to use the library, you would understand the code and the tests

Comment: From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*.

Comment: Hi, I have the same proble. Did you found the solution ?